# Iterate an array from the middle then the beginning

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I want to iterate through any array starting at an index that's close to the middle, go to the end then go to the beginning.
As an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


int a[]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,};

int i = 0;

for (i = 2; i < 6; i++){

    if (i == 6){
        i = 0;

    }

    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

How can I "reassign" the index to be zero when it reaches the end (index 6)

Comment: `if (i == 6)` ... it won't be. *How can I "reassign" the index to be zero when it reaches the end?* by starting another loop.

Comment: `i = i%6` does not work?

Comment: This probably needs some more context. LIke what does "close to the middle" mean. And perhaps why you want to iterate from the middle.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Good idea, though it will miss the element at `[6]`, but the OP was already doing that... If they don't really want to miss that one, then of course your idea of taking the modulo after incrementing would work for `% 7` or any other number of elements.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm _not_ a ninja.... :)

Comment: you won't reach `if (i == 6)` because you make `for (i = 2; i < 6; i++)` the max value of `i` is `5` change the if statement to `if (i==5)`.

Comment: @TZof but the size of the array suggests the OP should probably increase the number used in the `for` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood the question you want two for loops, one starting from the **middle** of your array and going to the **end** of the array and the second starting from the **middle** (minus one) and decreasing to the **beginning** of the array.
This is the code you can use, it is quite easy and works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, };

    int max = (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    int middle = (int)(max / 2);
    int i;

    for (i = middle; i < max ; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    for (i = middle - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect he wants to simply jump back to the begining but this is a good solution if he want to start from center and move out in both directions. You could also use one for loop with a conditional with zero starting with `print(i > length ? a[middle+i%length] : a[length-i -1])` something like that.

Comment: @danielson317 this can be a nice solution, be careful to the order of the output that is not specular...

Comment: Not sure I understand. This code doesn't care what the order of the array is or what it's content is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple write-up. Not tested so adjust as needed. The idea is have the counter start at 0 and add the value of start each time using modulus to make it relative.

```
int a[]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int start = length/2;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", a[(i+start)%length]);
}
```

And props to @SouravGhosh for pointing out modulus in the comments before I got this answer up.

Comment: `length` is wrong.  You forgot to divide by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks. fixed. Been too long since I used C :).